# SharedPreferences updating image according to variable change

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

How can I update the Image Icon according to the option selected by the user. The variable needs to be stored in shared_preferences. I tried this code but it's not working. Please tell me where am I wrong? The home screen needs to change immediately as the user navigates back after selecting the option.

homePage.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String selection;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getType();
    super.initState();
  }

  getType() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      selection = prefs.getString('type');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                  return SelectionType();
                }));
              },
              child: Text("Select Type")
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child: displayImageChoice(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  displayImageChoice() {
    switch(selection){
      case 'Mango':
        return Icon(Icons.ac_unit);
        break;
      case 'Apple':
        return Icon(Icons.backpack_outlined);
        break;
      case 'Banana':
        return Icon(Icons.offline_bolt);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

selectionType.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:saving_data_shared/optionSelector.dart';
import 'package:saving_data_shared/selectionPref.dart';

enum type {Mango, Apple, Banana}

class SelectionType extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SelectionTypeState createState() => _SelectionTypeState();
}

class _SelectionTypeState extends State<SelectionType> {
  type selectionType = type.Mango;
  bool isSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          OptionSelectorBar(
            elementDisplayText: 'Mango',
            isSelected:
            selectionType == type.Mango,
            onTap: () async {
              setState(() {
                selectionType = type.Mango;
              });
              TypePrefs.setTypePrefs('Mango');
            },
          ),
          OptionSelectorBar(
            elementDisplayText: 'Apple',
            isSelected: selectionType == type.Apple,
            onTap: () async {
              setState(() {
                selectionType = type.Apple;
              });
              TypePrefs.setTypePrefs('Apple');
            },
          ),
          OptionSelectorBar(
            elementDisplayText: 'Banana',
            isSelected: selectionType == type.Banana,
            onTap: () async {
              setState(() {
                selectionType = type.Banana;
              });
              TypePrefs.setTypePrefs('Banana');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

sharedpref.dart

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class TypePrefs {
  static Future<String> getTypePrefs() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString('typePref');
  }
  static Future<bool> setTypePrefs(String value) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.setString('type', value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your hompage widget is not updating when you set string in preference
try this

```
 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
              return SelectionType();
            })).then((value){
          setState(() {
          });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are calling 'getType()' which is asynchronous in the 'initState()', which is not. You could try wrapping the column you have in the body in a futureBuilder and pass the 'getType()' method as future instead of running it in the 'initState()'.